# How to refresh graphql query in parent component after a form is submitted in a child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

My attempt below is not causing the INVOICE_QUERY to be fetched or the Table component to be re-rendered.

A snapshot of the parent's Query component:

```
<Query query={INVOICES_QUERY} variables={{ orderBy: 'date_DESC' }} >
     {({ data, loading }) => {
     if (loading) return <Loading />;

     return (
      <Wrapper>
        <Form/> 
        <Table invoices={data.invoices}/>
      </Wrapper>
   ):
 }}
</Query>
```

A snapshot of the child's Mutation component:

```
 <Mutation mutation={CREATE_INVOICE}
   refetchQueries={[
    {
      query: INVOICES_QUERY,
      variables: {
        orderBy: 'date_DESC',
       },
     },
   ]} 
   awaitRefetchQueries
    >
      {(createInvoice, { error, loading, data }) => (
        <Formik
          render={formikProps => (
            <InvoiceForm
              loading={loading}
              error={error}
              {...formikProps}
            />
          )}
          onSubmit={(values, actions) => this.handleSubmit(values, actions, createInvoice)}
          initialValues={this.initialValues}
        />
      )}
    </Mutation>
```

The parent component displays a form for submitting invoices and a table that shows a list of invoices that have been submitted. When a new form is submitted in the Form component (child 1), executing a graphql Mutation, I would like the INVOICES_QUERY graphql query to refresh so that the Table component (child 2) displays the updated list of invoices. Thank you!

Comment: `refetchQueries` should cause the `INVOICES_QUERY` to be refetched, which should cause a rerender of the `Table` component with the new data. I'm guessing you're *not* seeing the component update then? Can you see the query being refetched in your browser's dev tools?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the Query component render prop has a refetch method. You can then pass this down and call it as needed.

```
<Query query={INVOICES_QUERY} variables={{ orderBy: 'date_DESC' }} >
  {({ data, loading, refetch }) => {
    ...
    <Form onSubmit={() => refetch()} />
    ...
  }}
</Query>
```

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#refetching

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to pass the refetch method of the Query component to the Form component and call refetch() on completion of the mutation.

In the parent component:

```
<Query query={INVOICES_QUERY} variables={{ orderBy: 'date_DESC' }}>
    {({ data, loading, refetch }) => {
      if (loading) return <Loading />;
```

Inside the Form component:

```
<Mutation mutation={CREATE_INVOICE}
      onCompleted={() => {
        this.props.invoiceSubmitted();
        this.props.refetch();
      }}
    >
```